# php regex - strip everything off <a> tags except href

Tags: php, html, regex

Another HTML with Regex question

I'm trying to strip everything off the `<a>` tags, except the href.

The following regex I put together does just that, until it finds a non-matching a tag (an a tag without a href reference)

Then it keeps looking until the next href, and then it takes it entirely.

Check:
http://regex101.com/r/zO0cX3

As you can see here, `&lt;a id=&quot;5quot;&gt;test&lt;/a&gt;` gets removed, even though it shouldn't.

the output should just be `<a href="blabla">blabla</a>`, so remove anything that becomes before href, after href, but still in between the `<a>` tag itself. If there is no href, the regex should ignore it and leave it be.

This is probably an easy solution, but I can't come up with it even what I try. Is there some way to "look" for the ending `>` even when there is no href?

Comment: `Another HTML with Regex question` i like it

Comment: sample output please. it will help us anser better

Comment: Check out the regex101 link I provided.

Comment: @Axon, do you want to strip off everything except keeping href and its value?

Comment: i saw the link but i dont understand what you want to keep and what you want to strip ?

Comment: Yes, the output should just be `<a href="blabla">blabla</a>`, so remove anything that becomes before href, after href, but still in between the `<a>` tag itself. If there is no href, the regex should ignore it and leave it be.

Comment: Why are you escaping them?

Comment: Escaping what exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML is not a regular language and cannot be correctly parsed by a regular expression. Use a DOM parser instead, so your code works even if the format of the markup changes in future. Here's one solution using PHP's [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/domdocument) class:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$errorState = libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); // don't display errors
$dom->loadHTML(htmlspecialchars_decode($html));

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node) {
    foreach ($node->attributes as $attr) {
        if ($attr->name !== 'href') {
            $node->removeAttribute($attr->name);
        }
    }
}

libxml_use_internal_errors($errorState); // reset the state
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/133833)

Comment: I think I'll just throw my entire code around, I thought I just had to replace simple tadbits with regex, but now it seems that it got harder and harder. I'll use this method instead, it seems a lot less error-prone than regex... Thanks

Comment: @Axon: I'm not sure what your final goal is. If I understand your question correctly: you were trying to remove all the attributes from the `<a>` links, ***except*** `href`. Or is it not what you were trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes, everything from <a> tags except href needed to disappear. I'm writing a parser that converts HTML code from one e-learning platform to another, and these two e-learning platforms have some differences that need fixing, otherwise the page won't work in the other e-learning platform. I've been doing it in regex for a while, but I think if I continue my code will become unreliable.

Comment: @Axon: Absolutely. HTML parsers are the way to go. I take it your problem's been solved?

Comment: Solved is a big word, but yeah, I think if I throw my code around the end result will be worth it. Too bad it took my stubborn head this long to move away from regex.