# Filtering Attributes from a link tag except href in PHP

Tags: php

I found the Answer [php regex - strip everything off <a> tags except href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937785/php-regex-strip-everything-off-a-tags-except-href) helpful, except it doesn't filter those whacky custom attributes like in this tag here:

```
<p>Video <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=foo" target="_blank" data-vivaldi-spatnav-clickable="1">on Youtube</a></p>
<p>And a Book <a href="https://www.amazonas.br/bar" target="_blank" data-vivaldi-spatnav-clickable="1">to buy</a></p>
```

The **target** Elements are removed fine, but the custom elements stay.

What I would expect would be something like

```
<p>Video <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=foo">on Youtube</a></p>
<p>And a Book <a href="https://www.amazonas.br/bar">to buy</a></p>
```

I used the php from the link above:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$errorState = libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); // don't display errors
$dom->loadHTML(htmlspecialchars_decode($str));

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node) {
    foreach ($node->attributes as $attr) {
        if ($attr->name !== 'href') {
            $node->removeAttribute($attr->name);
        }
    }
}

libxml_use_internal_errors($errorState); // reset the state
$str = $dom->saveXML();
```

Comment: Add the desired output from the sample tags you provided.  And congratulations for resisting the urge to parse HTML with regex!

Comment: thanks for the note - that missing " was just a typo. I fixed it.

Comment: @Nic3500 I imagine OP wants the same markup but with all attributes removed from the `<a>` elements except for `href`

Comment: Why `htmlspecialchars_decode()`?

Comment: @Nic3500 Updated, just like Phil guessed ;)

Comment: Reproduced here ~ https://eval.in/1024521

Comment: Well, that htmlspecialchars_decode was actually in the original Answer that is linked..;) I tried to remove it with no change in the outout

Comment: log out the result of the $node->attributes please

Comment: https://eval.in/1024601 @Chris

Comment: You may want to consider an XSLT solution as an alternative though that might be overkill :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the note here ~ http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnamednodemap.php#94346.

This is a classic example of mutating the collection you're iterating. Simple answer, start at the end and work backwards.

```
for ($i = $node->attributes->length - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    $attr = $node->attributes->item($i);
    if ($attr->name !== 'href') {
        $node->removeAttributeNode($attr);
    }
}
```

Demo ~ https://eval.in/1024619

Comment: Thanks, that looks good on the demo, on my final code however, it still doesn't work yet.. :/

Comment: @cukabeka don't know what else to tell you. You'll need to find out the differences between the demo and your final code